# ATI radeon graphics card and screen freeze problem

Tags: graphics-card

recently i upgrade my machine with new hardware component. my mother board is Gigabyte, processor Intel i3 3.6 ghz, ram 4 gb, graphics card ATI radeon 4350 1 GB. my OS installed is windows XP.

when i am trying to play call of duty black ops then screen gets freeze and when i try to play other game like medal of honour then suddenly game closed suddenly after 15 or 20 minutes. i am not being able to find out the problem. whether i have problem in RAM or Graphics card. i asked few hardware person and one of them told me that i should installed windows 7 rather than windows xp. is it true. please help me to understand the problem and also tell me what should i do to fix this problem. please discuss in detail. thanks in advance.

**Update:** yes i already install lates driver for ATI radeon 4350 but still the problem persist. do i need to install windows 7 instead of win xp because my processor is intel i3.

Comment: What are CPU/GPU temperatures under load?

Answer (score 3):

Windows 7 will help you find the right drivers for the graphic card much better and faster then Windows XP will.

Also, Windows 7 works much better with the card's fan, and electric efficiency.
I would also check the temperature of card when you play these games, maybe it is overheating.